# Django: Creating default value with post_save and Admin Inline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two objects, `Product` and `Variation`. `Variation` is defined as `ForeignKey` at product table. I want to set a default value for `Variation` which will be used if I don't create a `Product Object` with a `Variation` value. If a product is created with a `Variation` value, it shouldn't use the default value.

But when I run the code below, it always creates an object with using default `Variation`.

**models.py**

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...

def product_post_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    product = instance
    variations = product.variation_set.all()
    if variations.count() == 0:
        new_var = Variation()
        new_var.product = product
        new_var.title = "Default"
        new_var.price = product.price
        new_var.save()

post_save.connect(product_post_saved_receiver, sender=Product)
```

I am trying to get this output:

- MacBook Pro - Default
- iPhone 7 - 16 GB, 32 GB

Instead of that it returns this output:

- Macbook Pro - Default
- iPhone 7 - Default, 16 GB, 32 GB

Comment: fisrt pause and ask yourself whether you have the database design right.

Comment: @e4c5 what's your opinion for database? I think design right.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the product before the variations from what i understand, and each time you save a product, you give it the "Default" variation if it doesn't already have an existing variation. Since it does not have any variation upon creation, of course each product will have the Default variation.
What I think you should do instead (if I understood right), is create the product with no default variation. And then when you fetch the variations of a given product, you will return a default one if none exist in the DB

Comment: or, which is probably even best, is to give it the default variation like you do, but also override variation save method to remove the default variation on the same product if it exists. That way, the default variation is created at start, but then removed once you save the 16GB variation for example, leaving you with what you are trying to get

Comment: I create Variation at the sametime with Product. Because I use Inlines. How I remove defult variation one create process?